# How to align colorbar tick labels and lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, alignment, colorbar

I need to make a plot with a discrete colorbar in Matlab. I do this in the following way:

```
data = randi(10, 20);
imagesc(data)
my_colormap = rand(10, 3);
colormap(my_colormap)
cb = colorbar
set(cb,'YTickLabel',{'A';'B';'C';'D';'E';'F';'G';'H';'I';'J';})
```

Now my problem is that the colorbar tick labels and the small lines in the colorbar don't align nicely. How can I even the colorbar tick labels and the small lines better as illustrated in the following pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TickLabel on the colorbar each correspond to a value (a Tick). To place the TickLabels in the middle, you need to place the tick in the middle. To make this dynamic (so that It does not change when resizing the image) was I bit tricky I recall and I do not really recall. To set the ticks just once is not so hard though,

```
set(hCbar,'YTicks',RightYTicks);
```

**EDIT:**

On request I will post an example. This should give a hint of what to do.

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
cmap = jet(10);

[x, y] = meshgrid(x,y); %x and y grid

c = x-0.1; %Set color code to increase to the right
hFig = figure;
scatter(x(:),y(:),10,c(:),'filled'); % Simpler for the example
set(gca(hFig),'CLim',[0,10]);
colormap(cmap);
hCbar = colorbar;
set(hCbar,'YTicks',0.5:9.5);
set(hCbar,'YTickLabels',{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'});
```

For newer matlab version, the `YTicks` may have changed name to `Ticks` And `YTickLabels` may be called `TickLabels`.

Comment: thank you for your help, can I ask anyway, what is hCb and RightYTicks? I'm not so proficient with Matlab yet x) I guess hCb is cb in my code? Is RightYTicks a vector of values? say...RightYTicks = 1:10? Could you give me a MWE? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi sorry, hCb is handle for colorbar and RightYTicks are the correct YTicks. So for example for 7 colors in the color bar, you want to have the ticks at 0.5:1:6.5.